# Winsock recv() blocking clients app

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, recv

I'm trying to create simple C++ server-client application, which allows multiple users to connect to server. The problem is that after creating new thread for each client, recv function started to crash clients app.

Here is my code for creating new thread for each client connected:

```
while (ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, 0, 0)) {
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("\ninvalid client socket", GetLastError());
            continue;
        }
        unsigned threadID;
        HANDLE myhandleB = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &Server::receiveMessageThread, (void *) &ClientSocket, 0,
                                                   &threadID);
    }
```

And here is a method which is trying to receive a messages from server:

```
void waitForMessage() {
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );
}
```

After calling:

```
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
```

client app stops responding.

Comment: You seem to think that using threads is simple. *Wrong*.

Comment: Well. It's always good to learn

Comment: It looks like that if there was an error you then go on to use the socket with the error. And try yo be a bit more consistent in your naming of things.

Comment: Things to research regarding threads: locking, atomics, priority inversion, false sharing, race conditions, deadlocking. There's more, but if you wrap your head around that initially you are on a good path to using threads safely (and knowing why they are dangerous and tricky as hell).

Comment: There is no evidence here that the server ever sends anything.

Answer (score 1):

All of your client threads are receiving a pointer to the *same* `SOCKET` variable, so they are going to trample on each other. You need to pass a **copy** of the `SOCKET` to each thread instead.

You are also leaking the `HANDLE` that `_beginthreadex()` returns if successful, and leaking the accepted `SOCKET` if failed.

Try this instead:

```
// make sure this is declared as 'static' in the 'Server' class declaration...
unsigned __stdcall Server::receiveMessageThread(void *arg)
{
    SOCKET ClientSocket = (SOCKET) arg;
    ...
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    return 0;
}

...

while (true)
{
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, 0, 0);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("\ninvalid client socket", GetLastError());
        continue;
    }
    unsigned threadID;
    HANDLE myhandleB = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &Server::receiveMessageThread, (void *) ClientSocket, 0, &threadID);
    if (myhandleB)
        CloseHandle(myhandleB);
    else
        closesocket(ClientSocket);      
}
```